# Optimize jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, optimization

I have this code below for autocomplete feature of several inputTextbox. The input box also share same class ".wikiInput". When user typed something in either of them, a relevant autocomplete dropdown box should show up. Instead of hard code one by one. How do I group them in one using array or array group? Note the lookup has different arrays in different pages. Not every page showing all of the needed arrays.

```
    (function () {
        var cdTeamInput = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAssociation");
        if (cdTeamInput.length > 0) {
            cdTeamInput.autocomplete({
                deferRequestBy: 0,
                autoSelectFirst: true,
                lookup: txtAssociation,
                onSelect: function (value, data) {
                    cdTeamInput.val(value.value);
                    $(".wikiSubmit").click();
                }
            });
        }
    })();

    (function () {
        var cdSubjectInput = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSubject");
        if (cdSubjectInput.length > 0) {
            cdSubjectInput.autocomplete({
                deferRequestBy: 0,
                autoSelectFirst: true,
                lookup: txtSubject,
                onSelect: function (value, data) {
                    cdSubjectInput.val(value.value);
                    $(".wikiSubmit").click();
                }
            });
        }
    })();
```

---

so far what I got but still not working for cross-page array objects. Console keep saying I got undefined variables because not every page have all those arrays available. How to ignore the function if it doesn't exist in page? lookup.length>0 don't work for me.

```
function initAutocomplete(selector, lookup) {
  $(selector).autocomplete({
    deferRequestBy: 0,
    autoSelectFirst: true,
    lookup: lookup,
    onSelect: function (value, data) {
      cdSubjectInput.val(value.value);
      $(".wikiSubmit").click();
    }
  });
}

initAutocomplete("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAssociation", txtAssociation);
initAutocomplete("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSubject", txtSubject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you not simply add this:

```
if(!lookup) return;
```

or

```
if(typeof lookup === 'undefined') return;
```

Like here

```
function initAutocomplete(selector) {

  if(!lookup) return;

  $(selector).autocomplete({
    deferRequestBy: 0,
    autoSelectFirst: true,
    lookup: lookup,
    onSelect: function (value, data) {
      cdSubjectInput.val(value.value);
      $(".wikiSubmit").click();
    }
  });
}
```

### EDIT

If you do something like this:

```
if(txtAssociation){
  //do something
}
```

this will thow an error "undefined variable" if you dont declare txtAssociation before.

So you need to declare all of this variables in every page:

```
var txtAssociation,txtSubject;
```

and do this after

```
txtAssociation = ["v1","v2","v3"]; //Your array complete
```

Now when you do this:

```
if(txtAssociation){
  //do something
}
```

Finally works because now you have an undefined but declared variable.

Anyway i recommend you do something like this:

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAssociation" data-autocomplete="txtAssociation">
```

and you can call it

```
function initAutocomplete(selector) {

  var lookup = window[$(selector).attr("data-autocomplete")];
  if(!lookup) return;
  $(selector).autocomplete({
    deferRequestBy: 0,
    autoSelectFirst: true,
    lookup: lookup,
    onSelect: function (value, data) {
      cdSubjectInput.val(value.value);
      $(".wikiSubmit").click();
    }
  });
}
```

This works if txtAssociation is declared as a global variable.

This is not the best implementation of autocomplete, but works without bigger modifications.

### jQuery ready

```
$(function(){
    initAutocomplete("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAssociation", txtAssociation);
});
```

this is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initAutocomplete("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAssociation", txtAssociation);
});
```

You can use any to execute a function when the document is loaded completely.

Comment: lookup=[a,b,c]  a=[serious of arrays] b=[serious of arrays] so does c. And a,b,c are in different pages. in your way, I think this code would never work?

Comment: why not define an empty array when this is not available?

Comment: For that we need to know how are you defining txtAssociation or txtSubject, i think you are confused of which is the undefined variable.

Comment: Each of the variables are generated from back end and placed in the head as inline javascript with var txtAssociation = [hunderds of values], other variables generated in same way. So in my js file, I just use the variable in lookup code. Not sure if this explained how it is defined?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is when you do this initAutocomplete("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAssociation", txtAssociation); i will edit my answer for an explanation.

Comment: so can I declare the global variables in my .JS file that loaded after body content?

Comment: Yes, you can, but in that case you need to be sure that the variables are loaded, so you need to use function that use these variables on document.ready, check my last edit for a jquery implementation of document ready.